# Angular Directive for input Numbers only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, regex

I am creating a `directive` to restrict input box to accept numbers only. It should accept 1-9999999999, but no leading 0. It is working but after entering first number it is accepting all numbers and characters. Please help me to resolve this.it should accept 10, but not 01. For this my code is,

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="number" required="required" numbers-only="numbers-only" />
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
           if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
           var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/^[^1-9]*/g, ''); 
           if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
              modelCtrl.$render();
           }         

           return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = ''
}
```

FIDDLE: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DwKZh/2338/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an alternative `^0+` to `/[^0-9]+/g` so that the leading zeros could be removed:

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/^0+|[^0-9]+/g, ''); 
//                                         ^^^
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uj0exnu1/1/).

The `^0+` matches 1 or more (`+`) zeros that are at the string start (`^`).

Answer (score 0):

I have found this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/2776/)(not created by me). Hope this helps.

Directive:

```
fessmodule.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;


        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });


        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

P.S. I have not tested.

Answer (score 0):

well you just need to remove the first `^` from your pattern. here is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyn5m402/)

use this -

```
replace(/[^1-9]*/g, '');
```

you can use the below one to restrict 0 at beginning [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1hhmgp8/)-

```
replace(/^0|[^0-9]/, '');
```

Comment: no its not accepting 0 at all.. I guess this is what you wanted??

Comment: No I just want no leading 0. it should accept 10, but not 01.